# Jenkinsfile with string variable issue

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, groovydsl

I have a `Jenkinsfile` and parsing list of ports from input file,

```
pipeline {
  parameters {
    string(defaultValue: '4000', name: 'Port', trim: true)
  }
  
  stage('Test') {
    steps {
      script {
        echo 'Testing..'
        script {
          def data = readFile(file: 'list.txt')
          println(data)
          def Port = ""
          data.eachLine { line ->
            def arr = line.tokenize('\t')
            println "port: ${arr[0]}}"   # Prints values
            println "port: arr[0]"         # Prints name of Varible
            build quietPeriod: 2,
            job: 'Downstream_Jenkinsfile_Job',
            parameters: [string(name: 'Port', value: ${arr[0]})]  # <- ERROR HERE
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The line `parameters: [string(name: 'Port', value: ${arr[0]})]` gives error

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [archive,
...
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
```

I tried with:
`parameters: [string(name: 'Port', value: ${arr[0]}]`
`parameters: [string(name: 'Port', value: arr[0]]`

What is causing the issue ? I typecasted and no luck. Thanks

Comment: `value: arr[0]` is the proper syntax. What is the error thrown with that usage?

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard , With arr[0], I get error like,
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'String' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be

```
build quietPeriod: 2,
            job: 'Downstream_Jenkinsfile_Job',
            parameters: [string(name: 'Port', value: "${arr[0]}")]
```

a pipeline can interpolate the value if `$` is with in `""` and on your example you left the parameter value `${arr[0]}` but it has to be like `"${arr[0]}"`

Comment: Hi @Samit Kumar Patel, Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly :-)  I hope my looping logic is correct. Right? Anyway Marking your answer as helped me. Thanks.

Comment: In your looping logic, you are trying to get an index 0 value from loop for your downstream job - if this is your expectation, your logic is correct. 
but if your expectation is to invoke the downstream job as per the loop count with the proper current index value- your logic might not work.
if you could explain what you are trying , I might add some example

Comment: Thanks, I am just reading input file which has list of ports & URL, and a simple downstream job called passing port and URL in a loop. The code is,
def whole_file_data = readFile(file: 'ports_url_list.txt')
def arr
whole_file_data.eachLine { line ->
arr = line.tokenize('\t')
build quietPeriod: 2,
    job: 'downstream_job',
    parameters: [string(name: 'Port', value: "${arr[0]}"),string(name: 'URL', value: "${arr[1]}")]
}
Does closure takes care of Looping here?